# How to run paramiko demo_server.py?

Tags: python, paramiko

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paramiko/paramiko/master/demos/demo_server.py

I see the above demo_server of paramiko. But I don't see the instructions on how to run it. I run the following `./demo_server.py` command. But once I run `ssh robey@127.0.0.1 -p 2200`, the server fails. Could anybody let me know the complete steps on how to run this example? Thanks.

```
$ python3 ./demo_server.py
Read key: 60733844cb5186657fdedaa22b5a57d5
Listening for connection ...
Got a connection!
*** Caught exception: <class 'ImportError'>: Unable to import a GSS-API / SSPI module!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./demo_server.py", line 140, in <module>
    t = paramiko.Transport(client, gss_kex=DoGSSAPIKeyExchange)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 445, in __init__
    self.kexgss_ctxt = GSSAuth("gssapi-keyex", gss_deleg_creds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/ssh_gss.py", line 107, in GSSAuth
    raise ImportError("Unable to import a GSS-API / SSPI module!")
ImportError: Unable to import a GSS-API / SSPI module!
```

```
$ ssh robey@127.0.0.1 -p 2200
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Try "pip install python-gssapi"

Comment: Or edit the server code to disable GSSAPI: `DoGSSAPIKeyExchange=False`.

Comment: Can you pass the verbose flag to the **ssh** command. Do you see anything unusual there? Try restarting the ssh service. As the logs show a module seems to be missing, try `pip install gssapi` instead of `pip install python-gssapi` as it is stated on the **python-gssapi** PyPI description that **it is unlikely to be developed further.**

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work, make sure to go through these steps (Thank you Sandeep for the pip insight), chances are you may be missing the Kerberos dependencies:

1. You may need to perform `pip install gssapi` in the CLI if that has not already been done (I'm using the Windows Command Prompt, Linux/WSL might need `pip3` instead depending on your version of python)
2. From there you will need to import the gssapi library into the code at the top with the other imported libraries, so just call
   `import gssapi` in demo_server.py
3. After running demo_server.py again, the CLI should eventually say something like it is missing files located in `Program Files\ MIT\ Kerberos\ bin`, as Kerberos is a dependency for gssapi, you can install it from here:

   https://web.mit.edu/KERBEROS/dist/

Make sure you do custom install if you're not sure where it will be downloaded, so that you can set up the file location where the CLI says is missing in step 3 (Should automatically say `Program Files\ MIT`). I unchecked the boxes for auto-start and tickets, but not sure as to what your preferences may be. After all that, a computer restart is required.